# DBD::mysql complains "Character set 'latin1' is not a compiled character set"

Tags: mysql, character-set, perl

I think this boils down to "Am I doomed to upgrading mysql hoping the problem goes away?". I've seen a few of the same issues around the internet but with no guidance on a fix other than "Did you turn it off and on again?"

I've install Perl's DBI::mysql, but most of the tests fail because there's a character set problem:

```
 t/10connect.t ........................ Character set 'latin1' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
```

I wrote a script to investigate further:

```
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

print "Perl $^V\n";
print "DBI ", DBI->VERSION, "\n";
print "DBD::mysql ", DBD::mysql->VERSION, "\n";

$args{host} //= 'localhost';
$args{port} //= 3306;
$args{user} //= 'root';

my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:db=$args{database};host=$args{host};port=$args{port}";

my $db = DBI->connect( $dsn, $args{user}, $ARGV[0] );
```

The output has the same error from the tests:

```
Perl v5.18.0
DBI 1.631
DBD::mysql 4.027
Character set 'latin1' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
DBI connect('db=;host=localhost;port=3306','root',...) failed: Can't initialize character set latin1 (path: /usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/) at test.pl line 14.
```

I thought turning on UTF-8 in the `connect` would bypass the Latin-1 problem, but it's the same problem:

```
Perl v5.18.0
DBI 1.631
DBD::mysql 4.027
Character set 'utf8' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
DBI connect('db=;host=localhost;port=3306','root',...) failed: Can't initialize character set utf8 (path: /usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/) at test.pl line 14.
```

I think this is related to the MySQL bug [Bug #59243:Character set 'latin1' is not a compiled character set and is not specified](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59243), but MySQL begs off responsibility for this and says it's a FreeBSD problem (and that's where I'm working!). This might be more appropriate for ServerFault if that's true.

This is MySQL:

```
$ mysql --version
 mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.8, for FreeBSD8.0 (amd64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

The MySQL docs [(10.5 Character Set Configuration)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-configuration.html) say that I have to specify this set in *Index.xml*, and that's what the error message says, but Latin-1 is already in that file (and the file is at the path in the error messages):

```
<charset name="latin1">
  <family>Western</family>
  <description>cp1252 West European</description>
  <alias>csisolatin1</alias>
  <alias>iso-8859-1</alias>
  <alias>iso-ir-100</alias>
  <alias>iso_8859-1</alias>
  <alias>iso_8859-1:1987</alias>
```

They suggest getting a new *Index.xml* (although they don't say from where), so I copy the one I have on OS X (where all of this isn't a problem). That file was updated in 2012 whereas the one I had on FreeBSD was last updated in 2003. That didn't change the error message.

There's a FreeBSD bug [ports/153588: Character set 'latin1' is not a compiled character set and is not specified](http://freebsd.1045724.n5.nabble.com/ports-153588-Character-set-latin1-is-not-a-compiled-character-set-and-is-not-specified-td3599204.html), but it dies without any user guidance. I'd hate to take down everything to reinstall a FreeBSD port if this is a programming issue.

For what it's worth, this is only a problem because I'm installing on this on a different machine since my MySQL slave where I normally work is having all sorts of weird replication issues. I hopefully thought going right to the master (without creating a new user with the grants I need from where I am) would be easier than rebuilding the slave. Yeah, how's that working for me? :)

Comment: This is certainly not a MySQL server problem, it is related to the DBD connector -your solution will probably won't go away without recompiling the connector or upgrading it: I would certainly move it to serverfault, as it is related to your particular setup (be it MySQL's or your OS fault).

Comment: Almost anytime someone says "certainly", it immediately becomes so. This appears to be a problem with mysql on freebsd according to the vague reports.

Answer (score 1):

At MySQLBugs they suggested trying with binaries available at [MySQL Community Downloads](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) .

- *Downloaded*:

mysql-5.5.8-freebsd8.0-x86_64.tar.gz

- *Extracted to:*

/usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-freebsd8.0-x86_64

- *Linked to*

/usr/local/mysql

- *And re-compiled/re-installed p5-DBD-mysql against it by doing the following:*

`export PATH=/usr/local/mysql:$PATH
cd /usr/ports/databases/p5-DBD-mysql
make cleanenter 
make deinstall
make install`

**This is supposed to fix your perl module.**

Are you still following FreeBSD Bugzilla – Bug 153588 ?

**You may also refeer to http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=150959***

Hope you can keep going from here!